# Errormessage caused by Maven plugin manager - what is the reason?

Tags: java, maven

I get a obscure error meesage, if i want to build my maven project with command "maven clean install":

```
Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'com.samaxes.maven:minify-maven-plugin:1.7:minify': Unable to find the mojo 'minify' (or one of its required components) in the plugin 'com.samaxes.maven:minify-maven-plugin'
com/samaxes/maven/minify/plugin/MinifyMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0**
```

Was anybody an idea, how i can solve this problem?

//EDIT 
It is possible to solve this problem without changing the current JDK 6 to JDK 7 ?

//EDIT again

Ok i could build my maven project. I have done the follwoing step but i´m not sure, if this was a good way of solution:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.6</version>
</plugin>
```

I have changed the version from 1.7 to 1.6 and now i can build the maven project. But is that really the best solution?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is compiled for Java 1.7 and you don't have a JDK7 installed (at least Maven is not running with that JDK)

Answer (score 0):

This plugin was compiled for Java 7 and your system has previous Java version. Hence the problem with running `MinifyMojo`

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, this plugin is compile for Java 7.  You can either upgrade your version of Java or you can check if any of the previous [versions](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.samaxes.maven%22%20AND%20a%3A%22minify-maven-plugin%22) of your plugin were compiled with Java 6, or at least were compiled with Java 6 compatibility turned on.